# 日本語に違和感: カタカナ語の中にある半角スペース

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/we-need-your-help-translating-the-stack-exchange-engine-to-japanese

で指摘されていたのと同じ問題です。

- フッターにある「プライバシー ポリシー」
- ヘルプメニューの「ヘルプ センター」
- ヘルプメニューの「メイン サイト」

などなど。この半角スペースは無い方が自然だと思います。

正規表現+置換で一括変更できないでしょうか。

Comment: 半角スペースよりスペースなしの方がいいのか、間に「・」を付けるのか、どっちの方がいいですか？

Answer (score 4):

基本的に、スペースなしがよいと思います。

理由

- その方が一般的

  - 知らなかったのですが、翻訳スタイルガイドの中には、「カタカナの合成語は半角スペースまたは中黒 (・) で区切る」としているものもあるんですね
  - しかし、色々なウェブサイトを見てまわると、スペースなし派が多い印象です
  - また参考例として、[Androidドキュメント翻訳プロジェクトでスタイルガイドを検討した際に](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-docs-jp/709IkFQPgug/OnbkGEgxNJYJ)、「(半角スペースを使う、とする) 現在のスタイルガイドは珍しいほうで、多少の違和感はあるかもしれません」と結論づけられています ([最終的なスタイルガイドではスペースなしになっている](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/android-docs-ja/wiki/StyleGuide#h2-.E5.90.88.E6.88.90.E8.AA.9E))
- 個人的に、スペースなしの方が読みやすいと思う

  - 中黒 ・ があると心の中でそこでポーズを入れてしまいます

例外

- 「クリエイティブ・コモンズ」のような固有名称はその表記を採用する
- 3つ以上カタカナ語が連結したような長いフレーズでは、・を入れた方が読みやすいかも

  - これは見つけ次第修正していけばよいと思います

### いろいろなサイトの表記スタイル

スペースなし

- [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/jp)
- [ITMedia 情報システム用語辞典](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/im/articles/1111/07/news195.html)
- [Qiita](http://qiita.com/)

中黒とスペースなしが混在

- [jp.techcrunch](http://jp.techcrunch.com/)

半角スペースとスペースなしが混在

- [Ingress (Googleのゲーム) のヘルプ](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2799239?hl=ja&ref_topic=3261401)