# 翻訳ガイドラインを策定しませんか？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

[翻訳のガイドラインはありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2581/3054) で質問しましたが、今のところ翻訳のためのガイドラインは無さそうです。
ですので、ガイドラインの策定を提案いたします。
方向性が決まれば、コミュニティWikiとして投稿しなおし、必要に応じてメンテする形でどうでしょうか。

---

私案を以下に投稿いたしますが、その他に提案、指摘などあれば、よろしくお願いします。
また、私の提案はスタイルガイドという形で表記についてしか触れていませんが、翻訳作業のワークフローなども含めるべきかも知れません。その点もご意見お願いします。

Answer (score 5):

## スタック・オーバーフロー翻訳スタイルガイドライン（提案）

このガイドラインは、都度の翻訳作業において、完全な準拠を求めるものではありません。
翻訳の表記に迷った時や、表記の統一作業を行う際に参照して下さい。

### 基本

基本的に、「[JTF日本語標準スタイルガイド](https://www.jtf.jp/pdf/jtf_style_guide.pdf)」に従います。
ただし、

- JTF日本語標準スタイルガイドで複数のスタイルが示されており、選択が必要な点
- JTF日本語標準スタイルガイドに従わない点
- JTF日本語標準スタイルガイドで触れられていない点

などは以下の「補足・例外」に記します。

### 補足・例外

#### 文体

説明のための文章や、ユーザーに要求をする文章の文体は、敬体（ですます調）とします。
例：

- 「〜が必要です」
- 「〜を書いてください」

インターフェースの要素や、見出し、箇条書きに類するものは、常体（である調）か体言止めとします。
例：

- 「〜を投稿する」（ボタン）
- 「〜であること」（箇条書き）

ただし、質問形式の見出しは敬体（ですます調）とします。
例：

- 「〜とは何ですか？」

#### カタカナ複合語

カタカナ複合語を区切る際は、半角スペースを用います。
例：

- 「コミュニティー モデレーター」
- 「ユーザー プロフィール」

ただし、固有名詞などで中黒（・）の使用が定着しているものは、中黒（・）で区切ります。
例：

- 「スタック・オーバーフロー」
- 「クリエイティブ・コモンズ」

#### 全角文字と半角文字の間のスペース

JTF日本語標準スタイルガイドに従い、全角文字と半角文字の間にはスペースを入れませんが、Markdownの都合上必要な場合や、URIなどの識別子は、スペースで区切ります。
例：

- 「例えば http://example.com/ です」

#### スラッシュ

スラッシュ記号は、半角のスラッシュ（/）で表記します。
前後のスペースが原文にあれば、残します。
例：

- 「1/2」
- 「サイトデザイン / ロゴ」

#### 3点リーダー（...）

3点リーダー（...）は原文のまま、ピリオドを3つ重ねて表記します。
例：

- 「その他...」

#### ユーザーインターフェースを構成する記号

JTF日本語標準スタイルガイドに従い、文章に現れる記号は全角で表記しますが、UIの中で区切りや囲い、単位表記として用いられている記号は、原文が半角であればそのままにします。
前後のスペースが原文にあれば、残します。

例：

- 「低いスコア ($Score$)」（丸かっこ）
- 「回答日時: $date$」（コロン）
- 「$percent$% 未解決」（パーセント記号）

#### カタカナ語を用いず、アルファベットのままにする語

技術系サイトとして自然な範囲であれば、無理にカタカナ語を用いず、アルファベットのまま表記します。
その際、原文の語頭が小文字であっても、日本語の中での座りが悪ければ、大文字として構いません。
例：

- 「Markdownの書式」
- 「タグWiki」

#### 強調（斜体・太字）のマークアップ

[パーサーのバグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2478/3054)を回避するために、Markdownによる強調のマークアップにはアスタリスク（`*`）を使います。
原文のマークアップがアンダースコア（`_`）であっても変更します。

例：

- 「`*斜体*`」
- 「`**太字**`」
- 「`***太字かつ斜体***`」

Comment: <del>改めて JTF スタイルガイドを読んでみると、ガイド自体は「長いカタカナ複合語は中黒で区切る」と言っている一方、2.1.7 節の解説に書かれているとおり、JTF スタイルガイド自体はカタカナ複合語の間に記号を入れない選択をしたと書いていることに気づきました。</del>スタック・オーバーフロー上でのQ&A自体は主に日本語を母語とする‌​方々が日本語で行うものですので、カタカナ複合語（特に技術用語）に区切りが入ることは少ないように思います。となると、翻訳においてカタカナ複合語の区切りを採用した場合‌​、翻訳された部分とそうでない部分とで表記揺れが発生することになります。これは不自然かもしれないと思えてきました。カタカナ複合語の区切りは慣用的な例外を除いて使用しないことにするのは如何でしょうか。（翻訳に詳しくないので、悩んでいます。）

Comment: 私も「カタカナ複合語の区切りは慣用的な例外を‌​除いて使用しない」に一票。日常的にカタカナ複合語に区切りが入ることは少ない→翻訳の際も日常的な慣習に従った方が覚えるルールが少なくてよい、という利点もあるかと思います。

Comment: 翻訳スタイルの他に、翻訳物が Creative Commons になるよう、自動翻訳サイトは基本使えないことをどこかに書いておいた方が良いかもな、とふと思いました。

Comment: 建設的なご意見をどうもありがとうございます！nekketsuuuさんとentoさん、[カタカナ複合語の区切りなし](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/45/14055)のプラス票を反映させてください。

Comment: この投稿を、長いこと参照・メンテして頂いて光栄です。
しかしながら、「カタカナ複合語の区切りなし」への編集はロールバックさせて頂きました。
理由は2点です。
1. nekketsuuu さんのコメントの「JTF スタイルガイド自体はカタカナ複合語の間に記号を入れない選択をした」というのは誤読です。皆さんが、誤読に基づいて判断なさったなら、再考の必要があります。（投稿当時も指摘しました https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41528668#41528668 ）
2. この投稿は私の提案であり、私の意見として読まれると思います。皆さんの意見の集約ならば、独立した投稿を設け、コミュニティー Wiki としてメンテするのが自然と思いす。

Comment: 私は「カタカナ複合語の区切り」に意見は無いです。実際に作業する方がやりやすいように、何でもよいので早く決めればよいと思います。

Comment: @mjy おっしゃる通り Wiki として進めるべきでしたね   mjy さんのご投稿をわかりにくくしてしまってすみませんでした！

Comment: @aki さんが判断を進めるのは、良いことだと思います。
特にベータ版の間は、運営者が決定すべき事が沢山あると思います。
しかし、運営者側の方が個人のIDで活動し、それが全て反論や投票の対象になるというのは大変にストレスフルだと思いますので、同情申し上げます。
これはStack Exchange社のサービスの構造的な問題だと思います。

Comment: @mjy 公開から6年以上経過し、判断を進め方向性を決められるのは日本語版コミュニティとモデレーションチームだと思っています。それはCMの方も同意見であるはずで、投稿されているみなさんのお声を聞いて点と点をつなぐような作業を私はお手伝いさせていただいているだけですので...。これからベータ版を卒業してゆくというフェーズにおいて、mjy さんや公開当時から参加くださっている方のご協力を得ながら前進できたら最高なのかもしれませんが  。

Answer (score 1):

感嘆符(！)と疑問符(？)は**全角**として欲しいです。

前後が日本語(全角)に翻訳されているのにこれらの記号だけ半角となっている箇所は、文字が詰まって見づらく感じます。

例1
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

例2
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

JTFスタイルガイドからは「使うなら全角」、もしくは「和文では特に注意を引く必要がある場面以外では多用しない(句点に置き換える)」と読み取れます。