# "検索、、"に違和感

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

読点で終わっているのに凄く違和感を感じます。
もし"検索"に含みを持たせるなら下記はどうでしょうか？

- 検索...(ピリオド)
- 検索…(三点リーダ)
- 検索。。。(句点)

個人的には三点リーダが良いです。

Comment: 得票数が多いのと更新を反映したとのことで一旦承認しました。(よく分からないのですが、こういった意見を決める場合に先んじて更新はするものなんでしょうか？)変更があれば、また付け直します。

Comment: 言われて、確かに合意が形成されたと思われる前に、さっさと変更してしまいました。ただ、合意が形成されたと思われるのは、例えば最終投稿から2ー3日だったとして、 transifex で一つの文面なおすのに、議論して合意とって、それを確認してから反映のプロセスを厳密になぞるのは、、ちょっと重たすぎるかなという印象ではあります(必要翻訳文章量に対して)。イメージとして、 OSS 的に翻訳は更新できるので、ちょっと暇な時にサクッと直してもらって、それをモデレータ含むレビュー者が確定させる、異議が発生しそうな場合は、別途メタで議論する、メタ議論は多分翻訳ポリシーがどうだとかいう話になると思っていて、翻訳作業としては常に進めてもらって構わない、ぐらいのスタンスがいいのではないかなと思っています。

Comment: 次のデプロイまでに何度も更新できて、デプロイ方法に人手がかからないのであれば逐次更新でも良いのかな？とは思います。(要は二度手間になって誰かが苦労しないのかな？更新された後の意見は反映されてメンテされるのかな？という印象です)。翻訳でも多数派の意見が逐次反映されるのであれば全然勝手が分からないので、基本やりやすいようにが良いと思います。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 原文のまま半角で「...」がいいと思います

[翻訳ガイドラインの提案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2584/3054)の方にも含めていますが、3点リーダー（...）の翻訳は、原文のままピリオドを3つ重ねて表記するのがよいと思います。
ピリオド3つの ... は日本語に無い表現ですが、UIにおいては、続くものがあること、操作の対象になること、などを示すものとしてなじんでいますので使用して問題無いと思います。
既存の翻訳でも多用されています。

#### 「…」（全角）

日本語（全角）の3点リーター（…）は、欧文由来とは言え、現在は表わす意味の範囲が多少異なって来ていますので、これに変えてよいかの判断は文脈を考慮する必要があり、大変です。
フォントによっては点が中央に並びますので字形も異なります。
特に、UIの要素としては不適ですので、スタック・オーバーフローでこれを使用すべき場面は少ないです。

#### 「。。。」

区点の連続（。。。）はフォーマルな文では使われず、UIの要素としても不適です。

#### 「:」

コロン（:）はUIにおいては、要素に付けるラベルの一部としての役割を果します。
今回の場合ですと、「検索:」というラベルが入力欄の左に付いていた場合はコロンでよいでしょう。
しかし、実際はプレースホルダですので、原文ではコロンは使用されず、3点リーダーになっています。
このように、原文で ... になっているものをあえて : にすべきケースは無いと思われます。

---

以上が一般論ですが、今回のプレースホルダに関して、「...」に違和感があるので使用しないという事であれば、何もなし（「検索」のみ）がもっとも違和感が無い表記だと思います。

Comment: ひとまず、「検索...」でもって transifex を更新いたしました。

Comment: +1: 「何もなし」に賛成します。

Answer (score 3):

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/119173634

該当翻訳はこれだと思います。

個人的には、「検索: 」がいいのでは、と思うのですが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: 良いですね。よく見かけるので、その案も良いかと思います。

Comment: ひとまず更新したので、次のデプロイで反映されると思います。