# 翻訳時に斜体をどのように扱うべきか？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

新たに追加された英文を翻訳する際に、アンダーラインを用いた斜体記法が使われていることがあります。しかし、斜体記法にはいくつか問題があります<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)</sup>：

1. 斜体にしたい文字列の両端にはスペースが必要
2. 日本語で斜体が反映されないフォントがある

> ### 斜体と太字<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)</sup>
>
> 日本語の文中でこのような装飾を使う場合、直前・直後・またはその両方に半角スペースを挿入しないと正しく表示されないことがあります。また、メイリオなどの一部フォントでは全角文字が斜体になりません。

1つ目の問題点は、余分なスペースを追加していることから、スクリーンリーダーの読み上げの観点で好ましくない可能性があります。また2つ目の問題点は、書き手の強調したい箇所が読み手に正しく伝わらないことに繋がりかねません。

これらの問題を受けて、英文の斜体を今後どのように翻訳していくのが良いでしょうか？私が思いついたのは以下の3つです：

- このまま斜体を使う
- 太字に置き換える
- 太字と斜体を同時に使う

Answer (score 5):

斜体を斜体のまま翻訳する必要は無いと思っています。というのも、そもそも和文には歴史的にイタリック体が存在せず、単に文字を傾けたものは存在しますが、そこに特別な意味が付与されることはあまり無いためです。

英文ではイタリック体が強調や引用、学名や数式の変数名など、何かしらの意味が付与されて使われることがあるという理解をしつつ、その意味を保つように日本語に翻訳すれば良いと考えています。つまり、場合によっては斜体にせずそのまま書いたり、太字にしたりして良いと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

多くの場合、「このまま斜体を使う」が現実的かと思います。ただし、斜体マークアップを削除し、日本語として自然に強調される文章へ翻訳できる場合は、それに反対するものではありません。

他のマークアップで代替するのは止めた方がよいです。StackOverflowで使われている斜体マークアップは `<em>` 要素のようで、感覚的には「太字にするほどでは無い強調」に使われています。より強い強調（`<strong>` 要素）に太字のスタイルが使われているため、斜体の代替として太字や太字+斜体を使うとバランスが狂ってしまいます。

> 1. 斜体にしたい文字列の両端にはスペースが必要

この分かち書き問題は、アスタリスク(`*`)を使ってマークアップすることで概ね回避できます。
（以前、[翻訳スタイルガイドライン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2584/3054) として、「強調（斜体・太字）のマークアップ」の項で提案したことがあります）

> 2. 日本語で斜体が反映されないフォントがある

`<em>` 要素のスタイルとして斜体に加え、[text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)などのスタイルを当てるというのも案としては有り得ると思います。